# Jest tests passed but get an Error: Error serializing `symbol` returned from `getStaticProps` when rendering component. Why?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, next.js, ts-jest

When trying to pass JSX.Element type arguments as props to my component, I get a serializing error when I run `yarn dev`

but my jest tests pass.

Why do the rendering tests pass when in fact the component doesn't render properly?

Here is the code:

```
//Index.tsx
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const greeting = <DateFC date={new Date()} />;
  const saved_locations: JSX.Element[] = [];
  return {
    props: {
      greeting: greeting,
      saved_locations: saved_locations,
    },
  };
};
```

and the error

```
Server Error
Error: Error serializing `.greeting.$$typeof` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/".
Reason: `symbol` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

Passing tests that render Index.tsx using the render function from react-testing-library

```
 test("should contain a header section with a role of banner", () => {
    const { container: dom_node } = render(<Index greeting={<DateFC />} />);

    expect(screen.getByRole("banner")).toStrictEqual(
      dom_node.querySelector("header")
    );
  });
```

And Index.tsx component definition

```
function Index(props: IndexFCProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <header>{props.greeting}</header>
      <main>
        <section aria-label="weather in saved locations">
          {props.saved_locations}
        </section>
        <section aria-label="weather in favorite location">
          <WeatherTile withTime={false}></WeatherTile>
        </section>
      </main>
      <nav>
        <Nav></Nav>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```

I'm using the NextJs react framework.

Comment: That tests pass means nothing because you don't test getStaticProps, it's specific to Next and isn't used by React renderer. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation , "A required object with the props that will be received by the page component. It should be a serializable object". React elements aren't serializable and cannot be used there.

Comment: hmm, so I shouldn't lose confidence in my tests just yet? That was my major concern; that my tests are not delivering a value in catching errors.

Comment: Yes, the test is ok, it just tests React component itself and doesn't cover Nuxt part and needs to be augmented with e2e test. And you will have the same error in e2e.

Comment: @EstusFlask any idea how I can avoid this error? I need to pass my index component it's child components as props, because I can't do ``<Index><Child /></Index``, so I have to do ``<Index child={<Child/>} />``

Comment: getStaticProps is for fetching asynchronous data, <DateFC> doesn't belong to it. I see  no reason to keep <DateFC> in getStaticProps and not Index, they are parts of the same entity (Next's page) and aren't supposed to be used separately any way. It's not the same thing as <Index><Child></Index> because Index will always receive <DateFC> as greeting prop this way. Just hardcode it in Index, `<header><DateFC.../> </header>`.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I ended up hardcoding a default <DateFC/> like you suggested. So I'm able to pass in a custom <DateFC/> for my unit tests, but otherwise the default kicks in.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. It's viable but may be overengineered. For tests a comp can be mocked with jest.mock, Jest makes most test-oriented DI techniques redundant.